# Put contents above one another that are not beside each other in the markup

Tags: html, css

How can I modify the css below such that Box 3 is right below Box 1?

Without modifying any of the html or at least semantically box-1, box-2, box-3, box-4 has to be in this specific order with that layout.

All elements have flexible height.

https://jsfiddle.net/kuyfjho7/

```css
#parent {
  width: 1100px;
}

#box-1 {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}

#box-2 {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 800px;
}

#box-3 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}

#box-4 {
  background: gray;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="box-1">Box 1</div>
  <div id="box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div id="box-3">Box 3</div>
  <div id="box-4">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Layout needed:

[image]

Comment: `position: fixed; top: 200px;`

Comment: How should the page behave when scrolling? What you want it easy to do but I can't tell what happens when I scroll down.  Should some elements stick on the page while others move?  What elements have a flexible height?

Comment: @Justinas sorry, i forgot to mention that Box 1's height is dynamic.

Comment: @ChrisBarr thanks for the thoughtful questions! the page is just infinitely scrollable, no sticking. all elements have flexible height.

Comment: so all of the 4 elements can be any height?  Meaning it's possible for box 1 and 2 to contain things that will push the other boxes off screen?  Essentially you just have 2 columns then, with each one containing two stacked items

Comment: @ChrisBarr correct. i can't do 2 columns because i will need Box 1 to be the first element in html and Box 3 to be the third element in html.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible with the current html markup. Vaguely possible with wrapper divs and display contents when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox and specifying the `order` for each box might work.  This may not work as you want with variable height content though since these are all in the same "row" it will change the height of it's sibling as well.

```css
#parent {
  width: 1100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#box-1,
#box-3 {
  width: 200px;
}

#box-2,
#box-4 {
  width: 800px;
}

#box-1 {
  background: green;
  order: 2;
}

#box-2 {
  background: red;
  order: 1;
}

#box-3 {
  background: yellow;
  order: 4;
}

#box-4 {
  background: gray;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="box-1">Box 1</div>
  <div id="box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div id="box-3">
    <p>Box 3</p>
    <p>lots of content!</p><p>lots of content!</p><p>lots of content!</p><p>lots of content!</p><p>lots of content!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box-4">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping! its close. box-2's height is usually bigger than box-1's height, so i will need something that box-1 and box-2 having different heights but box-3 is always right below box-1.

Comment: essentially i don't want this "Unwanted space" https://jsfiddle.net/x816jpvq/

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure if what you want is entirely possible without changing the HTML.  If each "column" could be wrapped in a div this would be much much simpler and less hacky feeling.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, You could set display:flex CSS property to the parent div tag and set order as you wish to the child divs such as "order: 4".
And Set the "align-items:start || end || ..." to the child divs so that they can have their correct width and height. Hope this could help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).